# Is it possible to use shopify api from a store frontend?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, shopify

I can develop a shopify app, I can use the shopify_api (in rails),
I can do a lot of thing, but I could find the way to use the api from frontend...
I'd like to develop an ajax filter for frontend, but if I can't use the API, I won't be able to do it....

How can I reach the API from frontend? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can. If you have an App reachable by URL, and you want to HTTP Post|Get|Put|Delete to it, you just craft your Ajax call and make it to your URL.

Since you are now going to be doing cross-domain Ajax, you are responsible for implementing either CORS or using JSONP. Your choice. Both work well.

Even better, setup an App Proxy and you can securely accept Ajax to an endpoint and return whatever data you need to, knowing the request came from Shopify, so better than CORS or JSONP.

Note that if you wanted to implement filtering using product tags, you could do so using an App Proxy, and deliver your results from the App back to the shop storefront by rendering Liquid. That might suit you too.

So, you can certainly try your hand at using the API from the front-end.

Comment: The Shopify API does *not* seem to allow CORS requests (at least not anymore), so I'm not sure how this is possible without using an app proxy (which sort of defeats the purpose of doing AJAX from the frontend since you still need a backend to respond to the proxied requests). cf. https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/cors-issues-with-api-requests-to-checkfront-215166, https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/feature-request-cors-support-in-ajax-api-116381 etc.